# How to sync a Many to many relationship on Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, relationship

I want to know if there is a function I can call in Django ORM to update the intermediate table by passing an array of IDs

Im used to work with Laravel, and that framework has a very useful method called sync. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table is there something like that in Django? I was looking through the documentation but I can't find it. If there isn't, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: ORM is responsible for that through CASCADE value for `on_delete` argument, you just add those ids as a collection to the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't work with the ids in Django, but with the objects themselves. If you have a list of objects you want to set as the many-to-many relationship (making sure old relationships are removed), use `set()`. E.g. `publication.articles.set([article1, article2])`.

See [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more examples on how to work with many-to-many relationships.

If you have a form that lets users select the objects to choose, using a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) will return the list of objects in the form's `cleaned_data`, rather than the ids.

Comment: Im kinda new with the way Django handles forms so Im making my forms by hand on the html (like in Laravel)l. Is there a way to get an array of objects using an array of IDs? Or some way to push objects into an array if I need to build the array by hand

Comment: `Article.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 17])` returns you a queryset which you can use as argument to the `set` method.

Comment: But even if you code the HTML by hand, it would be better to use a Django Form to handle the data in python.

Comment: I don't quite get how the Django Froms work. Im doing them by hand because time constraints and because my experience with Laravel Im already familiar with how to do them. But Im interested in learning the advantages that Django provides Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The big advantage is mapping of input data to model data (ie from string input to python objects), including validation. It's also about consistency: hard-coding the name of fields in HTML means you need to make sure you name them the same in your views. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/) to get a good overview. And finally `ModelForm`s make it even easier to update objects that you store in your db.